# Problem while installing Deployer on JBOSS 6.1

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery, deployer

The infrastructure team is having issues installing Content Delivery Deployer in a JBOSS server.

The following list contains the technical details of the infrastructure:

- JBOSS 6.1
- Oracle 12.1.0.1
- Java 7
- Red Hat 6.9

The Infrastructure team deployed the `cd_upload.war` following these steps: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-8EF1BAC5-B311-4198-9166-80101C53CBC6

We had the error in both steps 19 and 20 (httpupload isn't starting)

Attached here you can find all the log files we have from JBOSS and from Content Delivery. Also attached all the configuration we have for the Deployer.

Anybody can help us with this problem? Any help will be appreciated.

JBOSS LOG

> 12:44:21,673 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-/10.105.42.36:8080 12:44:22,253 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "cd_preview_webservice.war" (runtime-name: "cd_preview_webservice.war") 12:44:22,253 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "cd_upload.war" (runtime-name: "cd_upload.war") 12:44:22,258 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on 10.105.42.36:4447 12:44:24,545 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in /content/cd_upload.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference. 12:44:24,545 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in /content/cd_upload.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference. 12:44:24,717 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in /content/cd_preview_webservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference. 12:44:24,718 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in /content/cd_preview_webservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference. 12:44:24,753 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader' 12:44:24,754 WARN [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader' 12:44:24,754 WARN [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader' 12:44:24,754 WARN [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General' for service type  ...  [...] 12:44:27,772 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (Sessions cleaner thread) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider 12:44:28,161 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (Sessions cleaner thread) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect 12:44:28,178 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (Sessions cleaner thread) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory 12:44:28,182 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (Sessions cleaner thread) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory 12:44:28,227 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (Sessions cleaner thread) HV000001: Hibernate Validator
>       4.3.1.Final-redhat-1 12:44:28,850 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (Sessions cleaner thread) HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update 12:44:28,851 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (Sessions cleaner thread) HHH000102: Fetching database metadata 12:44:28,853 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (Sessions cleaner thread) HHH000396: Updating schema 12:44:28,861 INFO  [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] (Sessions cleaner thread) HHH000262: Table not found: BINARYVARIANTS 12:44:28,866 INFO  [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] (Sessions cleaner thread) HHH000262: Table not found: BINARY_CONTENT 12:44:28,867 INFO  [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] (Sessions cleaner thread) HHH000262: Table not found: COMPONENT 12:44:28,868 INFO  [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] (Sessions cleaner thread) HHH000262: Table not found: COMPONENT_LINK_CLICKS 12:44:28,869 INFO  [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] (Sessions cleaner thread) HHH000262: Table not found: COMPONENT_PRESENTATIONS 12:44:28,870 INFO  [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] (Sessions cleaner thread) HHH000262: Table not found: COMPONENT_PRES_META_DATA 12:44:28,871 INFO  [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] (Sessions cleaner thread) HHH000262: Table not found: COMPONENT_VISITS 12:44:28,872 INFO  [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] (Sessions cleaner thread) HHH000262: Table not found: CUSTOMER_CHARACTERISTICS 12:44:28,873 INFO  [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] (Sessions cleaner thread) HHH000262: Table not found: CUSTOM_META 12:44:28,874 INFO  [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] (Sessions cleaner thread) HHH000262: Table not found: DYNAMIC_LINKS [...]

CD_CORE

> 2018-01-12 16:15:08,127 ERROR StorageManagerFactory - Configuration exception com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: No attribute found for: Class     at com.tridion.configuration.Configuration.getAttribute(Configuration.java:131) ~[cd_core.jar:na]   at com.tridion.storage.util.JDBCDataSourceBeanConfigurer.registerJDBCDataSource(JDBCDataSourceBeanConfigurer.java:58) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at com.tridion.storage.util.JDBCDataSourceBeanConfigurer.configure(JDBCDataSourceBeanConfigurer.java:42) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]     at com.tridion.storage.util.SpringContextDynamicConfigurer.configureDatasource(SpringContextDynamicConfigurer.java:69) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]   at com.tridion.storage.util.SpringContextDynamicConfigurer.configure(SpringContextDynamicConfigurer.java:44) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]     at com.tridion.storage.configuration.SpringConfigurationLoader.configure(SpringConfigurationLoader.java:26) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]  at com.tridion.configuration.step.ConfigurationStepLoader.configure(ConfigurationStepLoader.java:47) ~[cd_core.jar:na]  at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.configure(StorageManagerFactory.java:137) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at com.tridion.services.BaseService.(BaseService.java:113) ~[cd_core.jar:na]  at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.(StorageManagerFactory.java:104) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]   at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:84) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.(StorageManagerFactory.java:56) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]  at com.tridion.transport.HTTPSReceiverServlet.init(HTTPSReceiverServlet.java:86) [cd_upload.jar:na]     at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78) [wildfly-undertow-7.0.3.GA-redhat-2.jar!/:7.0.3.GA-redhat-2]   at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:239) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.getServlet(ManagedServlet.java:171) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:84) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78) [wildfly-undertow-7.0.3.GA-redhat-2.jar!/:7.0.3.GA-redhat-2]  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61) [wildfly-undertow-7.0.3.GA-redhat-2.jar!/:7.0.3.GA-redhat-2]   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:285) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:175) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]  at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:207) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]  at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:802) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_112]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_112]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112] 2018-01-12 16:15:08,132 ERROR StorageManagerFactory - Fatal error, unable to load the StorageManagerFactory com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: No attribute found for: Class     at com.tridion.configuration.Configuration.getAttribute(Configuration.java:131) ~[cd_core.jar:na]   at com.tridion.storage.util.JDBCDataSourceBeanConfigurer.registerJDBCDataSource(JDBCDataSourceBeanConfigurer.java:58) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at com.tridion.storage.util.JDBCDataSourceBeanConfigurer.configure(JDBCDataSourceBeanConfigurer.java:42) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]     at com.tridion.storage.util.SpringContextDynamicConfigurer.configureDatasource(SpringContextDynamicConfigurer.java:69) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]   at com.tridion.storage.util.SpringContextDynamicConfigurer.configure(SpringContextDynamicConfigurer.java:44) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]     at com.tridion.storage.configuration.SpringConfigurationLoader.configure(SpringConfigurationLoader.java:26) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]  at com.tridion.configuration.step.ConfigurationStepLoader.configure(ConfigurationStepLoader.java:47) ~[cd_core.jar:na]  at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.configure(StorageManagerFactory.java:137) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at com.tridion.services.BaseService.(BaseService.java:113) ~[cd_core.jar:na]  at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.(StorageManagerFactory.java:104) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]   at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:84) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.(StorageManagerFactory.java:56) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]  at com.tridion.transport.HTTPSReceiverServlet.init(HTTPSReceiverServlet.java:86) [cd_upload.jar:na]     at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78) [wildfly-undertow-7.0.3.GA-redhat-2.jar!/:7.0.3.GA-redhat-2]   at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:239) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.getServlet(ManagedServlet.java:171) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:84) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78) [wildfly-undertow-7.0.3.GA-redhat-2.jar!/:7.0.3.GA-redhat-2]  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61) [wildfly-undertow-7.0.3.GA-redhat-2.jar!/:7.0.3.GA-redhat-2]   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:285) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:175) [undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]  at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:207) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]  at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:802) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.3.25.Final-redhat-1]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_112]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_112]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]

## UPDATE:

cd_storage_conf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration Version="7.1"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
  <Global> 
    <ObjectCache Enabled="false">      
        <Policy Type="LRU" Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy">
            <Param Name="MemSize" Value="16mb"/>
        </Policy>
        <Features>
            <Feature Type="DependencyTracker" Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker"/>
        </Features>
    </ObjectCache>
    <Storages>
        <Storage Type="persistence" Id="Oracle_01" dialect="ORACLESQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
            <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="10" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
                <DataSource class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
                    <Property Name="driverType" Value="thin" />
                    <Property Name="networkProtocol" Value="tcp" />
                    <Property Name="serverName" Value="x" />
                    <Property Name="portNumber" Value="x" />
                    <Property Name="databaseName" Value="x" />
                    <Property Name="user" Value="x" />
                    <Property Name="password" Value="x" />
                </DataSource>
        </Storage>
        <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="xFile" defaultFilesystem="false">
            <Root Path="/x"/>
       </Storage>
    </Storages>
  </Global>
  <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="Oracle_01" cached="false">
    <Publication Id="x" defaultStorageId="Oracle_01" cached="false">
        <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="xFile"/>
        <Item typeMapping="Binary" cached="false" storageId="xFile"/>
    </Publication>
  </ItemTypes>
  <License Location="cd_licenses.xml"/>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: For me looks like configuration issue, can you update your question to share your cd_storage_conf.xml file

Comment: We faced a similar issue a few years ago - couldn't make deployer work properly on JBoss. Since nobody managed to find a solution, it was eventually decided to switch to Tomcat as a container for content deployer app.

Comment: The CD_CORE log shows a Configuration exception, so it would appear there is something wrong in one of the configuration files. **edit** your question with more details about your configuration files or compare them with a working environment if you have any.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate your help. We were also thinking that this is a cd_storage_conf issue but we validate over and over the same. Anyway, added the cd_storage_conf for your validation.

Comment: In addition, the error for the missing tables it looks like it's related cd_preview_webservice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the `class` attribute in the `DataSource` node, it's in lower case instead of upper case.

It should be like this:

`DataSource Class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"`

Comment: First of all, we copied not the latest version of the `cd_storage_conf.xml` in the current question by mistake. I've just updated with the one we had. We were working with @david-rodriguez in this solution and someone from the Infrastructure team came with this solution, even though SDL support didn't see the problem at the beginning. I can confirm this was the solution of the problem. Thanks for the support.